# How to Read Result from Two Different USB Ports and Differentiate Them

Tags: pi-2, rfid

I have a project where I control to access door with a Raspberry Pi. I want to connect two USB RFID readers to the Raspberry Pi. based on the read from each one, it will open a specific door. Right now I can control one access door with the Raspberry Pi, but what I want is to control two access doors and be able to open the access door that is for that specific USB RFID reader. Any Help?

Comment: It sounds like you need to hire a programmer.  If you want help show us exactly what you have done and explain which parts of it are not working.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the rest of the post